# PHP JSON decoding with one square bracket

Tags: php, arrays, json, function

Ok so I'm grabing market data with php and it's been working fine but I came across an api that gives me this 
`[{"market_id":"16","code":"DOGE","last_price":"0.00000136","yesterday_price":"0.00000140","exchange":"BTC","change":"-2.86","24hhigh":"0.00000150","24hlow":"0.00000132","24hvol":"6.544"}]`

and normally I grab it with this code

```
$data = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
$obj = json_decode($data);
$doge = print_r($obj->{'last_price'}."\n", true);
```

but it's not working because of the brackets `"["`. No other api has these.

How do I get around them to get the information?

Comment: so, `var_dump` data before decode and see what type is it.

Comment: `$obj[0]->{"last_price"}`

Comment: It's just a wrapper array.

Comment: FYI it's not true that "no other API has these [brackets]".  [Arrays are a perfectly normal part of JSON](http://www.json.org/) and _do_ appear in countless APIs.  You might just be seeing them for the first time, and that's fine.

Comment: you should use json_decode($json,true) so that jsonArray inside json are also taken care of

Comment: @Ray Toal, I meant apis that I've used so far.

Comment: Yep, all good, I was just saying you'll be seeing a lot more of them. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `print_r` of your object, you can see the structure like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [market_id] => 16
            [code] => DOGE
            [last_price] => 0.00000136
            [yesterday_price] => 0.00000140
            [exchange] => BTC
            [change] => -2.86
            [24hhigh] => 0.00000150
            [24hlow] => 0.00000132
            [24hvol] => 6.544
        )

)
```

So to access it , you can see the `last_price` is under the array index `0` , So you need to provide the `index` before your object.

#### Accessing ways..

```
echo $doge =$obj[0]->last_price;
```

(or)

```
echo $doge =$obj[0]->{'last_price'};
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/116280)

Comment: You should actually explain what the OP is doing wrong, not just give code solution.

Answer (score 0):

The response, you are getting is actually an `array`. First (and the only one in your case) element is an `object`. Therefore, in order to access this `object` you would simply call:

```
$array = json_decode($data);
$obj = $array[0];
$doge = print_r($obj->{'last_price'}."\n", true);
```